# Backup .ssh for new OS installation

Tags: 16.04, ssh

I'm planning to do a fresh OS installation, but first I want to backup my `.ssh` folder in order to keep my ssh keys. Can I copy it into a usb stick and if so how can I do this? Do I need to do any extra steps in order to "restore" the ssh keys on my new installation?

Comment: @Yaron I saw this post before posting mine, but it doesn't say anything about how to do the back up (or at least I didn't understand from what I've read)

Comment: @Lykos then editing you post, reflecting that you didn't understand would generate specific answers which aren't duplicates of original ones

Comment: @Lykos: The linked question doesn't mention how to perform the back-up and the restoration because they're a trivial copy (or archiving and extracting)  of the content of that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/)

> 6. How to backup an existing private/public key?
>
>    **Just copy files to your backup server or external USB pen/hard drive:**
>
>    - Copy files to  usb pen drive mounted at /mnt/usb *
>
>    `cp -avr $HOME/.ssh/ /mnt/usb/backups/`

Comment: the `/mnt/usb/backups/` doesn't exist

Comment: `/mnt/usb/backups` is just an example for a folder in the `usb` DOK. you can copy the `,ssh` folder to the USB DOK root folder

Answer (score 1):

For the user keys

```
sudo rsync -arv ~/.ssh/ /media/user/flash
```

where /media/user/flash is your mounted usb stick location

For the server keys

```
sudo rsync -arv /etc/ssh /media/user/flash
```

After your new set up is ready just perform the reverse.

*Warning* This will transfer your personal keys and your server keys (and they can be used to 'be' (not just impersonate) the old server (or you), so be careful what happens to the usb stick after you no longer require it...)